# Selecting libertinus italic loads bold italic font

Tags: fonts, fontspec, bold, libertinus

When using the [`libertinus`](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinus) font and compiling with `xelatex`, selecting the sans italic font with `\textit` causes the bold italic font to be loaded. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Sans}

\begin{document}
Test

\textbf{Test}

\textit{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a font called `Libertinus Sans Italic` in the `libertinus` folder, and it seems to be found according to the `.log` file:

```
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'LibertinusSans(0)' created for font 'Libertinus Sans' with
. options [Ligatures=TeX].
.  
.  This font family consists of the following NFSS series/shapes:
.  
. - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Libertinus
. Sans/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"Libertinus
. Sans/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold' (bx/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Libertinus
. Sans/B/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold small caps'  (bx/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"Libertinus
. Sans/B/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Libertinus
. Sans/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'italic small caps'  (m/itsc) with NFSS spec.: <->"Libertinus
. Sans/I/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold italic' (bx/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"Libertinus
. Sans/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. - 'bold italic small caps'  (bx/itsc) with NFSS spec.: <->"Libertinus
. Sans/BI/OT:script=latn;language=DFLT;+smcp;mapping=tex-text;"
.................................................
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Libertinus Sans BoldItalic:
The bold italic font is only italic according to the OpenType style field, so XeTeX picks it up as the regular italic font. You can overwrite this decision by using

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Sans}[
  ItalicFont={Libertinus Sans Italic}
]

\begin{document}
Test

\textbf{Test}

\textit{Test}
\end{document}
```

Alternativly you can switch to LuaTeX: The LuaTeX fontloader ignores the relevant OpenType values anyway, so the problem does not appear there.

Comment: I've reported the bug: https://github.com/libertinus-fonts/libertinus/issues/210

Comment: @Sverre That is not the right Bug Tracker: There is no Sans BoldItalic in the libertinus-fonts. It is an addition from the [https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinus-otf](`libertinus-otf`) package.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: which "style field" do you mean?

Comment: @Herbert The macStyle in the head table is (in binary) `10`, but it should be `11` because bit 0 represents bold and BoldItalic is bold. Also bit 5 in the fsSelection field of the OS/2 table should be set (It is an alias for bit 0 from macStyle) and also in OS/2 the field usWeightClass should be 700 (bold) instead of 400 (regular). I am not quite sure which of these field XeTeX uses but I would guess it is the macStyle.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usefilenames]{libertinus-otf}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
    Test

    \textbf{Test}

    \textit{Test}
\end{document}
```